# Add text to dynamically created HTML table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, html-table, dynamically-generated

I dynamically create a table based on the number of items in a Model.

I want to be able to add text the `<td>` element as the loop runs through each iteration.

The Razor is creating all of the elements, but the JQuery will not add the text for the `<td>` in the `GetTableData` function.

I have tested that data is coming back from the AJAX call, I have also tested that the data is real, so this part works.

My question is, how can I add the text dynamically to the `<td>` element at each iteration of the loop after the AJAX call is made.

My code is as follows:

```
 @{  Char celsius = (Char)176;
        int i = 0;      
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model.ChartTableData)
    {
        i++;

        string chartDiv = "chart" + i;
        string td1;
        string td2;
        string td3;
        string td4;
        string td5;
        string td6;
        string td7;
        string td8;
        string td9;
        string td10;
        string td11;
        td1 = "td1" + i;
        td2 = "td2" + i;
        td3 = "td3" + i;
        td4 = "td4" + i;
        td5 = "td5" + i;
        td6 = "td6" + i;
        td7 = "td7" + i;
        td8 = "td8" + i;
        td9 = "td9" + i;
        td10 = "td10" + i;
        td11 = "td11" + i;

        <script>
            google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);           

            function drawLineChart() {
                var serial = @item.SerialNumber;
                var uid = '@guid';
                var from = '@item.FirstReading';
                var to = '@item.LastReading';
                console.log('Chart: ' + serial + ' ' + uid + ' ' + from + ' ' + to);

                data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart' + @i));
                data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Data');               
                var parsedData = "";

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ReportGenerator/GetJsonChartData',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    type: 'get',
                    async: false,
                    data: { serial: serial, uid: uid, from: from, to: to },
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (d) {
                        GetTableData(serial, uid, from, to);
                        parsedData = $.parseJSON(d);
                        $.each(parsedData, function (index, item) {
                        data.addRow([new Date(item.ReadingDate), Number(item.ReadingValue)]);
                    });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error loading chart");
                    }
                });
                var options = lineChartOptions(serial);
                chart.draw(data, options);
            };

            function lineChartOptions(serial) {
                var options = {
                    title: 'Logger data: ' + serial,                   
                    legend: {
                        position: 'none'
                    },
                    height: $(window).height() * 0.5,
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Date',
                        format: 'dd-MMM-yy',
                        titletextStyle: {
                            color: '#333'
                        }
                    }
                }
                return options;
            }

            function GetTableData(serial, uid, from, to) {
                console.log('Table: '+serial + ' ' + uid + ' ' + from + ' ' +  to);
                var celsius = String.fromCharCode(176) + 'C';
                //var parsedData = "";

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ReportGenerator/GetJsonTableData',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    type: 'get',
                    async: false,
                    data: { serial: serial, uid: uid, from: from, to: to },
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (d) {                     
                        parsedData = $.parseJSON(d);                        
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error loading chart");
                    }
                });

                console.log(parsedData[0].Average);  

                var avg = parsedData[0].Average;
                var firstReading = parsedData[0].FirstReading;
                var lastReading = parsedData[0].LastReading;
                var loggerId = parsedData[0].SerialNumber;
                var stdDev = parsedData[0].StdDev;
                var mkt = parsedData[0].Mkt;
                var maxTemp = parsedData[0].MaxTemp;
                var minTemp = parsedData[0].MinTemp;
                var upperT = parsedData[0].UpperThreshold;
                var lowerT = parsedData[0].LowerThreshold;

                var timeAboveAlert = parsedData[0].TimeAboveEqualUpperAlert;
                var timeBelowAlert = parsedData[0].TimeBelowEqualLowerAlert;
                var notInAlert = parsedData[0].TimeNotInAlert;                

                $('#@td1').text(loggerId);
                $('#@td2').text(firstReading + " to " + lastReading);
                $('#@td3').text(avg + celsius);
                $('#@td4').text(stdDev + celsius);
                $('#@td5').text(minTemp + celsius + '/' + maxTemp + celsius);
                $('#@td6').text(timeAboveAlert);
                $('#@td7').text(timeBelowAlert);
                $('#@td8').text(notInAlert);
                $('#@td9').text(mkt + celsius);
                $('#@td10').text(lowerT + celsius + '/' + upperT + celsius);

                var max = Math.ceil((maxTemp + 1) / 10) * 10;
                var min = Math.floor((minTemp + 1) / 10) * 10

                return [min, max, lowerT, upperT];
            }

        </script>
        <div id="@chartDiv" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%;"></div>
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="width:100%; font-size:small;">
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th colspan="4" style="font-size:small; background-color:black; color:white;"><h6>Performance Data and Information</h6></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Logger ID</th>
                <td width="25%" id="@td1"></td>
                <th width="25%">Min/Max Thresholds</th>               
                <td width="25%" id="@td2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Date Range</th>                
                <td width="25%" id="@td4"></td>
                <th width="25%">Time: Value &lt Min</th>
                <td width="25%" id="@td5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Average</th>                
                <td width="25%" id="@td6"></td>
                <th width="25%">Time: Value &gt Max</th>
                <td width="25%" id="@td7"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Lowest/Highest Value</th>              
                <td width="25%" id="@td8"></td>
                <th width="25%">Time: Within Min/Max </th>
                <td width="25%" id="@td9"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">Std. Deviation</th>              
                <td width="25%" id="@td10"></td>
                <th width="25%">Time: Out of Min/Max</th>
                <td width="25%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">MKT </th>             
                <td width="25%" id="MKT"></td>
                <th width="25%"></th>
                <td width="25%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer this question, I have to say there're quite a lot of bugs in your code.

1. You're registering `OnLoadCallback` several times and defining the same functions several times :

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ChartTableData)
{
    <script>
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart); 

    function drawLineChart() {
        // .... assign @guid, @item  ... to locals
    }

    function lineChartOptions(serial) {
        // ...
    }

    function GetTableData(serial, uid, from, to) {
        // ...
    }
    </script>

    ...
}
```

What make it worse, you're assigning `@item` to function locals within a `foreach loop`, that will make the last defined function valid only.

2. You're invoking ajax in a wrong way. They're asynchronous :

```
function drawLineChart() {

     $.ajax({
         // ...
         success: function (d) {                           // async success
            GetTableData(serial, uid, from, to);           // async ajax
            parsedData = $.parseJSON(d);
            $.each(parsedData, function (index, item) {
            data.addRow([new Date(item.ReadingDate), Number(item.ReadingValue)]);
         });
     });
     var options = lineChartOptions(serial);
     chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Note the `$.ajax()` is `async`. As a result, the `chart.draw(data,options)` runs before the `GetTableData()`.

---

As for your question:

> My question is, how can I add the text dynamically to the  element at each iteration of the loop after the AJAX call is made.

Since you want to modify the DOM multiple times, it's not efficient to search the elements by `$("#td1")`, `$("#td2")`,`$("#td3")`,... and change their text times and times.

We could define a common template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="table-template" >
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="width:100%; font-size:small;">
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th colspan="4" style="font-size:small; background-color:black; color:white;"><h6>Performance Data and Information</h6></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Logger ID</th>
            <td width="25%">${td1}</td>
            <th width="25%">Min/Max Thresholds</th>               
            <td width="25%">${td2}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Date Range</th>                
            <td width="25%">${td3}</td>
            <th width="25%">Time: Value &lt Min</th>
            <td width="25%">${td4}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Average</th>                
            <td width="25%">${td5}</td>
            <th width="25%">Time: Value &gt Max</th>
            <td width="25%">${td6}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Lowest/Highest Value</th>              
            <td width="25%">${td7}</td>
            <th width="25%">Time: Within Min/Max </th>
            <td width="25%">${td8}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Std. Deviation</th>              
            <td width="25%">${td8}</td>
            <th width="25%">Time: Out of Min/Max</th>
            <td width="25%">${td9}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">MKT </th>             
            <td width="25%"id="MKT">${td10}</td>
            <th width="25%"></th>
            <td width="25%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

(The names `td1`，`td2` ,etc are not good, you could change it to be `loggerId` ,`reading` as you like)

Let's define a simple function to render this template :

```
<script>
    function renderer(templateStr){
        var itemTpl = templateStr.split(/\$\{(.+?)\}/g);
        return function render(model){
            return itemTpl.map((token,idx)=> idx%2 ===0 ?  token : model[token]).join('');
        };
    }
</script>
```

And now we can render the template multiple times as below:

```
<script>
    // model list
    var dataList= [ /*...*/ ];  // by ajax , or render it on server side 

    // get the template string
    var tmpl= document.getElementById("table-template").innerHTML;
    // generate a render function to render the above template
    var render = renderer(tmpl);

    for(var i =0; i< dataList.length;i++){
        // construct a model via `dataList[i]`
        // e.g: 
        var model = {td1:"td1-"+i,td2:"td2:"+i,td3:"td3:"+i,td4:"td4:"+i,td5:"td5:"+i,td6:"td6:"+i,td7:"td7:"+i,td8:"td8:"+i,td9:"td9:"+i,td10:"td10:"+i};

        var table = render(model);                  // the template string
        var wrapper=document.createElement("div");  // create DOM element
        wrapper.innerHTML= table;
        document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
</script>
```

Here you can get the dataList by `ajax` or render it on server side. All you need is to loop this array, render the template as string with different model and finally update the DOM.